# When did the Kompromat move from the boiler to being buried?

Tags: plot-explanation, bodyguard

A potential plot-hole in the TV-series *Bodyguard*, but when would it have been possible for the Kompromat (tablet) to have been buried in the grounds near David Budd's flat?

We see him preparing to meet Chanel, prior to his kidnap, by removing his gun from a secret compartment in his gas boiler and replacing this with the Keys to Julia Montague's flat and the tablet containing the compromising information. 
However, when he returns to his flat surrounded by Police having not had the chance to return to his flat in the meantime, he sends his wife to retrieve a length of rope and a spade with which to dig up the tablet from a garden below.

As it is not explained, or hinted-at as an off-camera action, perhaps we are to believe that this was always the hiding place and something else was stored in the boiler compartment? 
(Or perhaps as Lucy Lawless said in The Simpsons, Wizards did it?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While "plot-hole" is a logical conclusion (and not necessarily incorrect) there is *some* evidence of PS Budd hiding something **and then changing his mind and hiding it somewhere else**.

There's an element of mis-representation to the audience to increase the dramatic tension.

On one occasion, we see Budd hide his pistol behind the boards to his bathtub but when that same place is searched by police (*tension rises*) .... *it's not there*, instead it seems Budd has moved it to above the light fitting (the same place he sets the trap for Longcross).

It's not beyond that realm of possibility that having initally put the kompromat in the boiler he (off-screen) changes his mind and then buries the device and we pick up the action as he puts the gun in his belt ready for the supposed meeting with Chanel.

As I said, mis-direction of the audience is likely the primary aim but a plot-hole is not beyond logical bounds.

Comment: I think that would be too big of a plot hole, it looks more like audience misdirection. Maybe he changed the kompromat before the meeting with Chanel, fearing that someone could get to his place again (which happened later with Longcross)